# OpenFDA: BAD_REQUEST when searching with URL encoded inputs

Tags: openfda

I am trying to search some of the "free text" fields that have values with commas, apostrophes, etc. With the encoding I have tried all combinations of quotes, parenthesis, etc. however it always results in an error.

I have tried URL encoding and other approaches that seem [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) compliant, however I always seem to get this error:

{
  error: {
    code: "BAD_REQUEST",
    message: ""
  }
}

Here's an example of a search:
http://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?limit=1&search=product_description:(Today%27s+Harvest)

[The above should search for Today's Harvest]

Is this type of search possible/supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't allow embedded single-quotes in search strings. You will have to get creative. The following query appears to get find what you are looking for: http://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?limit=10&search=product_description:%22Harvest(TM)%22

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive response.  However you might want to look to support this in the future as this seems (naive?) like a fairly straight-forward feature.

Answer (score 1):

We concur. Query errors should return a real value, not just an error.  For instance, providing an error when a count = 0 is not useful to anyone.  Not supporting embedded single-quotes in search strings is also short-sighted.  Either adjust the data to remove apostrophes or provide a more robust error response.